# Setting up tab-completion of paths in bash or zsh to resemble tcsh

Tags: bash, zsh, tcsh, tab-completion

I’m a long time tcsh user, but all the cool kids seem to be using either bash or zsh nowadays (that is, completion patterns for git or stuff are available for bash and zsh, rarely for tcsh).

My problem is that both shells have behaviours regarding tab-completion of paths that drive me crazy, and I’m having much trouble finding how to change them to my liking.

Here’s a couple of examples of what I’m used to doing in tcsh that the others do differently:

- `/u<TAB>` completes to `/usr/`
- Then tab lists the contents of `/usr/`
- `/usr/li<TAB>` completes to `/usr/lib` and lists `lib/` and `libexec/`
- Pressing tab a second time completes to `/usr/lib/`
- Pressing tab a third time lists the contents of `/usr/lib/`

In bash, no matter how many times I hit tab, it will never go past `/usr/lib`, requiring me to type the slash, which I don’t want to do.

In zsh, `/usr/li<TAB>` first completes to `/usr/lib`, then another tab lists `lib/` and `libexec/`, a third time tab completes to `/usr/lib/`, and all subsequent tabs cycle between `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/libexec/`. I have no idea how to get past this point. I just want to go from `/usr/li` to `/usr/lib`, then `/usr/lib/`, then list its contents.

Same goes for python. In tcsh, I type `pyt<TAB>`, it completes to `python` and lists `python`, `python2.5`, `python2.6`, etc, then a second tab settles for python and add the space. In bash it requires me to type the space and in zsh it cycles endlessly like in the first example.

Any help in taming these shells would be greatly appreciated. I don’t really want to spend time tweaking the other aspects of these shells until I solve the problem above.

Comment: Part of learning a new environment is getting used to how it works. `man bash` `/completion`

Comment: I can’t help but think that this comment is both condescending and suggesting that I adapt to how bash works. Please correct me if I’m wrong, I’d love to.

Comment: It's not meant to be condescending, but it is an inevitable fact that different software likely has slightly different features.

Comment: Hence my asking, because me not finding a way to do something does not necessarily mean that it cannot be done. :) Like the `rec_exact` option suggested below for zsh: it does exactly what I want, but I don't remember it popping up in my searches, and even if it did, I'm not sure I'd have understood that it was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well done on describing your requirements precisely, but I'm not sure I actually understand what you want to do if there's an ambiguity, e.g. after `/usr/lib`, what you expect the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to do.

If I try tcsh, after `/usr/lib`, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key only lists `lib` and `libexec`. You can reproduce this effect in zsh with `setopt no_auto_menu`, but this may change the behavior in ways you don't like in other cases. If you also do `setopt rec_exact`, the behavior looks like what you describe: after `/usr/li`, <kbd>Tab</kbd> inserts `b`, then another <kbd>Tab</kbd> inserts `/`, and a third lists completions in `/usr/lib/`.

The zsh completion options are documented [under “Completion” in `man zshoptions`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Completion-2).

Comment: It's exactly that, thanks a lot. In the meantime I also found out about oh-my-zsh, started tweaking my prompt and looking for an alternative to Apple's Terminal that supports customisation of the colours. It's gonna be fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

For bash: in your `~/.inputrc` put:

```
set show-all-if-unmodified  on
```